# Arcpy export shp to kmz with transparency

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, kmz

I'm trying to export massive shp to kmz aplying simbology.

The code without transparency works good:

```
    import arcpy, os  
    workspace = r'C:\\folder\\of\\the\\workspace\\'  
    in_symbology_layer = 'lyr.lyr'
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace  
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype = "FeatureClass", type = "Polygon"):  
        for filename in filenames:  
            lyrname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(filename, lyrname)
            arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (lyrname, in_symbology_layer)
            arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(lyrname, lyrname + '.kmz')
```

When I try to export it with the **transparency** it doesn't work:

```
    import arcpy, os  
    workspace = r'C:\\folder\\of\\the\\workspace\\'  
    in_symbology_layer = 'lyr.lyr'
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace  
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype = "FeatureClass", type = "Polygon"):  
        for filename in filenames:  
            lyrname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(filename, lyrname)

            lyrname = arcpy.mapping.Layer(in_symbology_layer)               
            lyrname.transparency = 50 

            arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (lyrname, in_symbology_layer)
            arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(lyrname, lyrname + '.kmz')
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
import arcpy, os  
workspace = r'path' 
symbologyLayer = 'lyr.lyr' 
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace  
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype = 
"FeatureClass", type = "Polygon"):  
for filename in filenames:  
     lyrname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]  
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(filename, lyrname)
     arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyrname, symbologyLayer)
     yourLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyrname) 
     yourLayer.transparency = 50 #as a percentage
     arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(lyrname, lyrname + '.shp.kmz')
```